# install aws cli on rhel 7.x server running on Azure

Tags: azure, pip, boto3, aws-cli, rhel

I am trying to get AWS CLI installed on Azure RHEL 7.x server in python virtual environment.
I am running into issues with it, this is what I have done so far

```
    pip install boto3
    pip3 install boto3
    aws s3 ls
```

I am getting an error
"Traceback (most recent call last):
import awscli.clidriver
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in module

I see how to fix the issue with changing the sed -i -e 's//lib///lib64//' /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py  at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1656445

My question, How can I point my virtual env to point to python3

Thanks

Comment: Why not create python 3 virtual env? Seems you've created python 2 virtual env.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I point my virtual env to point to python3

We have executed below commands to create virtual environment for python3.6 & activating the venv as well on Azure Virtual Machine running with RHEL7.8 image.

```
$ scl enable rh-python36 bash
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.3

$ python -V  # python now also points to Python3 
Python 3.6.3

$ mkdir ~/pydev
$ cd ~/pydev

$ python3 -m venv py36-venv
$ source py36-venv/bin/activate
```

For more information about python3.6 installation on RHEL you can refer [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel#tl_dr) documentation.